# Input accepted by GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I  also need help getting my variable named "guess"  to work. I made it a parameter also in hope of getting it to work. I have to make a guess my number program with a GUI interface the code I have so far is:

```
from tkinter import*
import random  

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize the frame. """
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)  
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self,guess):
        self.pw_lbl = Label(self, text = guess)
        self.pw_lbl.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.pw_ent = Entry(self)
        self.pw_ent.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.submit_bttn = Button(self, text = "Submit", command = self.reveal)
        self.submit_bttn.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

    def reveal(self):
         contents = self.pw_ent.get()
         if guess == the_number:
             message = "You got it right!"
         if guess > the_number:
             message = "lower..."
         if guess < the_number:
             message = "higher..."

print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!")
print("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
print("Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.\n")
the_number = random.randint(1, 100)

root = Tk()
root.title('Guess my number')
root.geometry('350x150')

app = Application(root)
```

Comment: Instead of just saying it doesn't work, explain what it does wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you've added a `guess` parameter to `create_widgets`, but you haven't passed any value for that parameter when you *call* `create_widgets`. So, you're just going to get this:

```
TypeError: create_widgets() missing 1 required positional argument: 'guess'
```

But meanwhile, what value did you want there? All you want is some static string, like `"Guess"`. So why even add one as a parameter?

The only place you need a `guess` variable is in the `reveal` function. So make it a local variable there.

Inside `reveal`, you've already go this:

```
contents = self.pw_ent.get()
```

That `contents` is going to be a string, like `"25"`. And you want `guess` to be the corresponding number, like `25`. So, just call `int` on `contents`.

Also, you create a variable named `message`, but don't do anything with it. Maybe you wanted to change the contents of the label? Or print it to the console the way you print the startup banner? Without knowing what you wanted to do, it's hard to know what exactly to suggest, but you certainly wanted to do *something* with it.

One last thing: you forgot to call `mainloop` on either `root` or `app`. Without that, the program will just create the GUI off-screen, then immediately quit without ever displaying it.

It's still a little clunky—it's a hybrid GUI/console app, you've got a global `the_number` when you probably should have a member, the variables all have odd names (did you copy and paste them from somewhere else, like a fake login interface, or is `pw_ent` supposed to be meaningful for a guessing game?), etc.—but it will work:

```
from tkinter import*
import random

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize the frame. """
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)  
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.pw_lbl = Label(self, text='Guess')
        self.pw_lbl.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.pw_ent = Entry(self)
        self.pw_ent.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.submit_bttn = Button(self, text = "Submit", command = self.reveal)
        self.submit_bttn.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

    def reveal(self):
         contents = self.pw_ent.get()
         guess = int(contents)
         if guess == the_number:
             message = "You got it right!"
         if guess > the_number:
             message = "lower..."
         if guess < the_number:
             message = "higher..."
         print(message)

print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!")
print("\nI'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
print("Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.\n")
the_number = random.randint(1, 100)

root = Tk()
root.title('Guess my number')
root.geometry('350x150')

app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```